# cocos2d make low res for testing

Tags: iphone, ios, background, cocos2d-iphone

im using an image on the background  of a cocos 2d app,

In the simulator shows the background ok,
but in the phone 4s[retina], and in simulator on retina,

doesnt show properly,

I have read that to make the @2x I need to use the -hd suffix, [doing lots of things to make it work]

but for the moment and for my tests, i Would like to keep it in low resolution so the background and all shows fine to do my tests,

so how to make it work on low res?

edit:
here the difference:

proper image, iphone simulator:
[image]

wrong image, simulator retina
[image]

thanks a lot!

Comment: "doesn't show properly" isn't describing the problem

Comment: You do know that the one image is the iPhone Simulator, the other the iPad? The iPad is NOT a Retina device and will use the SD images.

Comment: hi, thanks, yes is the simulator for the iphone retina, it just haves the frame like an ipad haha, by the way its working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image is in SD format (480x320 pixels) then simply turn off Retina display support. Look for the line in app delegate that sends the `enableRetinaSupport` message to CCDirector.

If your image is in HD format, simply change its name to end in "-hd", for example "image-hd.png". Then it will display correctly on Retina displays. If you want to also support standard resolution, scale the image down by 50% and save it as "image.png".

Answer (score 0):

How about just resizing your image (the one you're using in your background) - to the size you actually have available on screen?
You can do this programatically with CGRectSize.